# how to I define measurement filter from other table in tabular

Tags: dax, tabular

I am trying to make measure that  gets sum of amt column where versiontype column = ative how do I write dax formula for that measure?

Comment: versiontype column is from version table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let's say your fact table is called Sales. It has a Sales Amount called Amt. The table is linked to a Version table with a VersionType field that includes a value of "Active".
You could create a new measure for Active Sales as follows:

```
ActiveSales :=
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Sales[Amt] ),
    'Version'[VersionType] = "Active"
)
```

Comment: Thanks Rory! that formula helped me a lot